# Android: SQL Insert query

Tags: java, android, mysqli, insert

I have two tables mainly the user table and the products table. I am having problems trying to store the userid into the products table. The products table will store the userid information.

user table
userid(primary key)
name
email
address

products table 
productid(primary key)
userid
productname
cost

how can i insert the user.uid into the product.userid?

```
public function storeProducts($userid, $productname, $cost){


        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

$id = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT userid FROM users WHERE "); // what should i write over here?


        mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE);


        if ($result) {

            $product_id = mysqli_insert_id($con); // last inserted id
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM product WHERE productid = $product_id");

            return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what the hell is this **$**?!

Answer (score 0):

$id = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid=$userid ");

how can i insert the user.uid into the product.userid?
but as you mention above you need inner join query for doing this

Comment: I am sorry that was a typo!

Comment: what do you mean by typo?

Comment: i was trying out the code and forgot to remove that line.